# Creating a node problem, any idea occur segmentation fault?

Tags: c

any idea what occur the problem ?

idea:

1. insert a new node to front in link list.
2. create a new node
3. pass the function address of new node to decide insert at front.

thank you.

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
}*HEAD, *TAIL;

int main(){
    int temp;
    printf(" |-> Insert front : ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    *tempNode = myInsert(temp);
    insertFront(tempNode);
}

Node myInsert(int num){

    // create new node
    Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = num;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return *newNode;
}

void insertFront(Node *newOne){

    if(HEAD==NULL){
        printf(" |-> insertFront - HEAD : List empty, adding node - %d.\n", newOne->data);
        newOne->prev = newOne;
        HEAD = newOne;
    }
    else{
        // insert front
    printf(" |-> insertFront - List : Adding node - %d.\n", newOne->data);
        newOne->next = HEAD;
        HEAD->prev = newOne;
        HEAD = newOne;
    }
}
```

[1]    2947 segmentation fault  ./a.out
FAIL: 139

Comment: Don't return `*newNode`, return the `newNode`. This  `return *newNode;` --> `return newNode;`

Comment: it will occur error when i remove that * in return function.

Comment: not sure about the problem on creating a node function  `Node myInsert(int num)` or insert function `void insertFront(Node *newOne)`

Comment: I added few observation in my answer, check.

Comment: I though `insertFront(&tempNode);` can using call by address to done the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in the code you mentioned, firstly here

```
Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

what's the `Node` ? You need to `typedef` the `struct Node`. For e.g

```
typedef struct Node{
        int data;
        struct Node *prev;
        struct Node *next;
}Node; /* first typedef it */
Node *HEAD,*TAIL;
```

Secondly, here

```
insertFront(tempNode);
```

you are passing `tempNode` to `insertFront()` and changes with `tempNode` in `insertFront()` won't reflect in calling function as it treats as call by value. You need to pass the address of `tempNode`. for e.g

```
insertFront(&tempNode);
```

Also `myInsert()` should be returning `newNode` not `*newNode`.

Try this version:

```
typedef struct Node{
        int data;
        struct Node *prev;
        struct Node *next;
}Node; /* first typedef it */
Node *HEAD,*TAIL;

Node* myInsert(int); /* declaration */
void insertFront(Node **); /* declaration */
void printNode(Node *); /* declaration */
int main(void){
        int temp;
        printf(" |-> Insert front : \n");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        struct Node *tempNode;
        int itr;
        printf("enter no of nodes you want to insert onto list \n");
        scanf("%d",&itr);
        for(int i = 0;i< itr; i++) {
                tempNode = myInsert(temp);
                insertFront(&tempNode); /* need to pass address else changes in insertFront won't reflect here */
        }
        printNode(tempNode); /* fun for printing Node info*/
        return 0;
}

Node* myInsert(int num){
        // create new node
        Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->data = num;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
}

void insertFront(Node **newOne){
        if(HEAD==NULL){
                printf(" |-> insertFront - HEAD : List empty, adding node - %d.\n", (*newOne)->data);
                //newOne->prev = newOne; /* not required as myInsert() already did this */
                HEAD = *newOne;
        }
        else{
                // insert front
                printf(" |-> insertFront - List : Adding node - %d.\n", (*newOne)->data);
                (*newOne)->next = HEAD;
                HEAD->prev = (*newOne);
                HEAD = (*newOne);
        }
}
void printNode(Node *temp) {
        while(temp) {
                printf("%d\t",temp->data);
                temp = temp->next;
        }
}
```